# Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the set $A$

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

Let $A$ be a nonempty set and $C$ is a partition of $A$.

A relation $\sim$ is defined as:
$$For \ x, y \in A, x\sim y\ \ if \ and \ only \ if \ there \ exists \ U \in C \ such \ that\ x \in U and\ y \in U .$$

I have to prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the set $A$. Earlier in this problem, I had to prove that $\sim$ was an equivalence relation on $A = \{ a, b, c, d, e\}$ (it was part a of this 4 part problem). In this case, the set $A$ is being generalized. I'm confused on how to prove this without having specific "examples" that I could use like I did in part a of this question.

Comment: Your reference to "earlier in this problem" is confusing. Are you sure it's the same $A$ and relation here as there? Your question is straightforward if you omit the last sentence: check the properties you need for an equivalence relation, [edit] the question to tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: I meant earlier in the problem that I was assigned for homework, this part that I'm asking a question about is for part c of the 4 part question. The last sentence is referring to what I had to do in part a of the question. The difference between part a and part c is that the set is being generalized in part c.

Comment: You will need to know the definition of a partition.  The properties of an equivalence relation should follow almost immediately.  For example, $\sim$ will be reflexive because for any $x\in A$ you will have by definition of partitions some $U\in C$ such that $x\in U$.  It is clear that given that $x\in U$ it follows that simultaneously $\color{red}{x}\in U$ and $\color{blue}{x}\in U$ so $\color{red}{x}\sim \color{blue}{x}$.  (*Color is of course not necessary here, but it feels silly to just repeat $x\in U$ four times in a row and have it be clear why I would do so*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows directly by definition of partition.  A partition of a set $A$,  $C$ is a class of sets $U_\alpha$  so that every element of a $A$ is in some $U_\alpha$ and the $U_\alpha$ are disjoint.

Reflexive says:

There exists a $U$ so that  $a\in U$ and $a \in U$.

By definition of partition there is some $U$ so that for each $a\in A$ there is a $U$ so that $a\in U$. (and therefore $a \in U$).

Symmetric says:

If there exists a $U$ so that $a,b \in U$ then there exists a $U$ so that $b,a \in U$.

(Don't need to say anything more.)

Transitive says:

If there exists a $U$ so that  $a,b \in U$ and and $V$ so that $b,c\in V$ then there is a $W$ so that $a,c \in W$.

By definition of partition, the partitioning sets are disjoint.  So if $b\in U$ and $b \in V$ then $U= V$.  So if there exists a $U$ so that $a,b \in U$ and if there exists a $V$ so that $b,c \in V$ then $U=V$ and $a,b,c \in V$.

Comment: To the proposer: The definition of a partition C of a set A requires that for all $a\in A$ there is EXACTLY ONE $U\in C$ such that $a\in U.$