# Let $a \in A \ and\ U \in C \ such\ that\ a \in U\ $. Prove that $[a] = U\ $.

Tags: equivalence-relations, set-partition

If you refer to this link and the question, it's this same question, this is the last part of the [4 part question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3019461/603668) .

The equivalence relation $\sim$ is defined as: 
$$\textsf{For }x,y\in A,x\sim y\textsf{  if and only if there exists }U\in C\textsf{ such that }x\in U\textsf{ and }y\in U$$

I have to prove that $[a] = U\ $ given that: $$a \in A\textsf{ and }U \in C\textsf{ such that }a \in U$$ I mentioned that the definition of a partition says that: $$\textsf{For all }a \in A\textsf{ there  exists }U \in C\textsf{ such that }a \in U$$... but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: First, what is $[a]$?

Comment: $[a]$ is an equivalence class @GrahamKemp

Comment: For what equivalence relation?

Comment: I assume you are trying to show a step in the problem of showing that partitions are effectively equivalence relations and vice versa on a set.  I further assume that you have some specific equivalence relation $\sim$ for your specific partition $C$.  You are likely intended to show that the equivalence class $[a]$ is *equal* to the part $U$.  There is a big difference between "$[a]\in U$" and "$[a]=U$."

Comment: Yes I do, if you refer to this link and the question, it's this same question, this is the last part of the 4 part question. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3019461/603668

Comment: oops that was a typo, i meant "=" @JMoravitz

Comment: So, the rigorous answer will depend on how exactly your partition or how exactly your equivalence relation is defined.  If your equivalence relation was defined based on your partition such as defining $a\sim b\iff \exists U\in C$ s.t. $a\in U$ and $b\in U$... then just remember your definition of equivalence classes...  $[x]=\{y~:~x\sim y\}$, that is to say $[x]$ is the set of all elements that are in the same $U$ as $x$ is.  Use your definitions!

Comment: The equivalence relation $\sim$ is defined as:
$$For \ x, y \in A, x\sim y\ \ if \ and \ only \ if \ there \ exists \ U \in C \ such \ that\ x \in U and\ y \in U .$$ @JMoravitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sequal to question [Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the set $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019461/prove-that-sim-is-an-equivalence-relation-on-the-set-a)

In that you prove that $x,y$ belonging to the same partitioning set is an equivalence relation.

Here you are asked to prove if $a\in$ the partitioning set $U$ that:

$[a] =\{x\in A| a\sim x\} = U$.

As $a \in U\subset A$ and that is distinct ($a$ is *not* in any other partitioning set) then

$[a] =\{x\in A| a\sim x\}= \{x\in A| a, x \in U\} = \{x\in A|x\in U\} = \{x  \in U\} = U$.

That's all.